# DIV's with percentage width doesn't work (no borders, no margin/padding)

Tags: html, css, width, percentage

i created my own progressbar and got some problems

i have a complete .box with width=90%

in that box i have the .progress div with width= 100

in the .progress div i got .left-free div 10%, .progressbar 80%, .right-free 100%

in the .progressbar i got 4 divs .grey 30%, .violet 30%, .brown 30%, .blank 0%

the problem is don't know why .grey, .violet, .brown aren't the same size!

edit: (the .blank div is just a spacer.. everything is fine with that.)

i don't use margin or padding or any borders.
the border around the .progressbar was realized with box-shadow.

**my html code:**

```
<div id="box">

    <div id="progress">

        <div class="left-free">10% free</div>

        <div class="progressbar">
            <div class="grey" style="width:30%">30%</div>
            <div class="violet" style="width:30%">30%</div>
            <div class="brown" style="width:30%">30%</div>
            <div class="blank" style="width:0%">0%</div>
        </div>

        <div class="right-free">10% free</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**my css code:**

```
body
    {
        width:100%;
        background-color:#eee;
        padding:0;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
#box
    {
        width:90%;
        padding:0;
        margin:2% auto;
        background-color:#eee;
    }
#progress
    {
        width:100%;
        padding:0;
        margin-bottom:10%;
    }    
.left-free
    {          
        width:10%;
        float:left;
        box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);         /* right */
    }
.progressbar
        {
            position:relative;
            width:80%;
            float:left;
            background-color:#ffffff;
            box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),         /* top */
                        inset 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);         /* bottom */
        }
.grey {background-color:grey;}
.violet  {background-color:violet;}
.brown  {background-color:brown;}
.blank {background-color:#ffffff;}

.grey,
.violet,
.brown,
.blank
    {
        height:100px;                                            
        float:left;
        margin-top:1px;
    }

.left-free,
.progressbar,
.right-free
    {
        height:102px;                                           
    }
.right-free
    {
        width:10%;
        float:left;
        box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);         /* border left */
        text-align:right;
    }
```

i created a screenshot and put a green bar with the same width over all 3 boxes!
on the .violet and the .brown div i have an spacer on the right end (hope you can see it on image)

[image: problem]

here is a crop for a better view

[image: croped]

you can see the running code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4Kvr/)

second example: [jsfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/rryR6/)

any ideas why the boxes don't have the same size?

edit: i uploaded the html to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=296HMu7y)

Comment: I inspacted the jsfiddle in chrome and the gray,violet and brown have the same width and height.

Comment: I inspected your example as well, Chrome on Windows and Safari on Mac, I used guides in photoshop and all 3 are identical.

Comment: really? i use firefox on win7 and got the problem as described and the same on internet explorer 9

Comment: I would say that the problem lies in the green bars. Put a fixed width in them and see what happens (like 200px).

Comment: but i created the green bars with photoshop..

Comment: i edited my question and uploaded the html to pastebin.. maybe you can check that again?

Comment: I just checked the fiddle on chrome, safari, and firefox. They look fine to me on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**change grey and brown width to 30.1% or just remove borders progressbar**

Comment: why to 30.1%? i don't have any bordes.. the border is just a boxshadow and doesnt have any effect to the width of the bar

Comment: this is because you don't reset your css, read about this http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Comment: what exactly you want to do with these divs???? so maybe i can provide you another solutions...

Comment: ok.. let me try to explain.. one day has 1440minutes.. the colorboxes (30%) are each 480minutes minus 10%. so i got 384minutes for each box and this gives me a width of 30%. my php script checks now the working time and gives me the result in width. so i get the result of the efficiency in my company.. for example here you can see that the grey box mad a good job http://jsfiddle.net/ka7gn/ here we have an overcapacity. thats why i need the white box.. my php script is working fine.. but the template has a bug.. which isn't fine for the statistic :D